# Technique to run an event receiver from console app

Tags: list, event-receivers, console-application

There's a imported list with 500.000 items and an event receiver attached to it (itemAdded/Updated). I need to run the event receiver on older items meeting specific criteria but I don't want to update the items nor duplicate the code of the event receiver.

I'm thinking of creating a class inside the event receiver and import the .dll to a console app but I can't figure out the steps. The event receiver has not been implemented yet. The console app could be run on the server.

Has anyone done it before and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a solution that has three projects: a class library containing the functionality, the console app, and the event receiver. The console app and event receiver would each have a reference to the class library project.